# Sending messages using pipe - C

Tags: c, pipe

I want to make `NO_PROC` processes, such that every process reads messages from its parent, and then writes those messages and one more message to its child, except in the case of the last process which writes its messages to `stdout`. So the *i'th* process will receive *i-1* messages and will send to child *i* messages. I must use pipe to communication between processes. I wrote code but something is wrong and I can't find any bug :/. When `NO_PROC = 5` I want the output to look like 4 lines with "my message", but in output I have one line: "my message" and 3 empty lines, like 3 messages are empty string :/. Note, `err.h` is my library which gives me function `syserr()` when something went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "err.h"

#define NO_PROC 5
#define BUF_SIZE 20

char message[] = "my message";
int parent;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_PROC; ++i) {
        int pipe_dsc[2], buf_len;
        if (pipe(pipe_dsc) == -1)
            syserr("Error in pipe\n");
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
            syserr("Error in fork\n");
        else if (pid == 0)
            parent = pipe_dsc[0];
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if ((buf_len = read(parent, buf, BUF_SIZE - 1)) == -1)
                    syserr("Error in read\n");
                buf[buf_len < BUF_SIZE - 1 ? buf_len : BUF_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
                if (i == NO_PROC - 1)
                    printf("%s\n", buf);
                else if (write(pipe_dsc[1], buf, sizeof(buf)) != sizeof(buf))
                    syserr("Error in write\n");
            }
            if (i < NO_PROC - 1 && write(pipe_dsc[1], message, sizeof(message)) != sizeof(message))
                syserr("Error in write\n");
            if (wait(0) == -1)
                syserr("Error in wait\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "something isn't ok". Please be more specific. For example, please tell us the exact expected output and actual output.

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally forgot about it.. So when NO_PROC = 5 I want output look like:

Comment: Please add the info into the question. Not as comments.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think your over complicating it and/or using the wrong approach. You don't have to send *i* messages to the *ith* process. Since the *ith* process is a copy (fork) of the *i-1th* process it has already received *i-1* messages, and just needs one more. It's a rather symmetrical (and academic) problem.

Here is an example (*robust error checking omitted*). Note this relies on atomic pipe writes, which is fine as long as you not writing message greater that `PIPE_BUF` (see `man pipe`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void syserr(char * msg) { printf("%s\n", msg); exit(1); }
#define NO_PROC 5
#define BUF_SIZE 100
char message[] = "my message ";

int main() {
    int message_len = 0;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_PROC; ++i) {
        int pipe_dsc[2], buf_len;
        if (pipe(pipe_dsc) == -1) {
            syserr("Error in pipe\n");
        }
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            syserr("Error in fork\n");
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            close(pipe_dsc[1]);
            int n = read(pipe_dsc[0], buf+message_len, sizeof(buf));
            message_len = strlen(buf); // Assume message is null terminated string.
            if(i == NO_PROC -1) {
                printf("Process %i: received '%s'\n", i+1, buf);
            }
        }
        else {
            close(pipe_dsc[0]);
            write(pipe_dsc[1], message, sizeof(message));
            wait(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deserve a big +1 to understand the question (but you have a lot of warning :p). Well, I didn't want to annoying with this but @JonathanLeffler do it...

Comment: This leaks a lot of file descriptors.  Whether that actually matters is a separate question; in this context, maybe not, but in general, you need to be less cavalier about leaking pipes.  In particular, processes may not terminate properly if they need to detect EOF on pipes and too many processes have the same pipe open for writing (and/or reading).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler definitely worth noting for the OP, but I took it as an academic question since the forked processes don't really do any real useful work and I couldn't see what real useful work they might be intended to do in such a structure.

Comment: Update: Not perfect but added some pipe closing.